# Running grep From Java Program

Tags: java, linux, process, grep, processbuilder

I've spent the past 3 days without much luck on google on how to run a grep process from within Java.

I have the following code to run a grep process, however, I am only getting the first line of the response.

```
package com.example.parser;


import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            Process process = new ProcessBuilder("grep", "-rni", "\"public static void main(\"", "/home/user/dev/java/").start();

            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(process.getInputStream()));

            String line = "";
            while((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                System.out.println(line);
            }

            System.out.println("Exit Code: " + process.exitValue());

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

I am only getting the following response:

```
Binary file /home/user/dev/java/Parser/parser/bin/com/example/parser/Main.class matches
Exit Code: 0
```

When I should be getting the following response:

```
Binary file /home/user/dev/java/Parser/parser/com/example/parser/Main.class matches
/home/user/dev/java/Parser/parser/src/com/example/parser/Main.java:10:  public static void main(String[] args) {
/home/user/dev/java/Parser/parser/src/com/example/parser/Main.java:12:          Process process = new ProcessBuilder("grep", "-rni", "\"public static void main(\"", "/home/user/dev/java/Parser/parser").start();
Exit Code: 0
```

I am wondering why I only get output for the first finding? Is grep forking several processes to run the search and I'm only getting a handle on the first one?

---

I have also tried running the process from a Thread:

package com.example.parser;

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            Analyzer analyzer = new Analyzer();
            analyzer.start();
            analyzer.join();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}


package com.example.parser;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;

public class Analyzer extends Thread {

    public Analyzer() {
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            Process process = new ProcessBuilder("grep", "-rni", "\"public static void main(\"", "/home/user/dev/java/Parser/parser").start();
            process.waitFor();
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(process.getInputStream()));

            String line = "";
            while((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                System.out.println(line);
            }

            System.out.println("Exit Code: " + process.exitValue());

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

---

As well as the following:

```
package com.example.parser;

import java.io.IOException;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            Process process = new ProcessBuilder("grep", "-rni", "\"public static void main(\"", "/home/user/dev/java/Parser/parser").start();
            process.waitFor();

            Analyzer analyzer_is = new Analyzer(process.getInputStream());
            Analyzer analyzer_es = new Analyzer(process.getErrorStream());

            analyzer_is.start();
            analyzer_es.start();

            analyzer_is.join();
            analyzer_es.join();

            System.out.println("Exit Code: " + process.exitValue());

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}

package com.example.parser;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;

public class Analyzer extends Thread {

    InputStream is = null;

    public Analyzer(InputStream is) {
        this.is = is;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(this.is));

            String line = "";
            while((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                System.out.println(line);
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

As suggested by the following article: http://www.javaworld.com/jw-12-2000/jw-1229-traps.html

Comment: Is there an ultimate goal besides learning how to use `ProcessBuilder`?

Comment: @Dave: not sure what you mean with your question?

Comment: Exactly that; if you're trying to do something with Java code, particularly anything like "parsing" as the name implies, not sure why you'd be trying to do it this way. In other words, if your ultimate goal is some form of Java program manipulation, why are you doing it like this?

Comment: If by Java program manipulation you mean modifying Java source code, then no, that's not the goal... the goal is to parse the output of the grep command

Comment: To what end? This seems like something better suited to a non-Java language/process.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to solve the issue by launching a shell with the -c flag. The following code does what I had originally intended:

```
package com.example.parser;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            List<String> commands = new ArrayList<String>();
            commands.add("/bin/sh");
            commands.add("-c");
            commands.add("grep -rni --include \"*.java\" \"public static void main(\" /home/user/dev/java/Parser/parser");

            Process process = new ProcessBuilder(commands).start();
            Analyzer analyzer_is = new Analyzer(process.getInputStream());
            Analyzer analyzer_es = new Analyzer(process.getErrorStream());

            analyzer_is.start();
            analyzer_es.start();

            process.waitFor();

            analyzer_is.join();
            analyzer_es.join();

            System.out.println("Exit Code: " + process.exitValue());

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}


package com.example.parser;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;

public class Analyzer extends Thread {

    InputStream is = null;

    public Analyzer(InputStream is) {
        this.is = is;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(this.is));

            String line = "";
            while((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                  System.out.println(line);
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is probably because you don't wait for the grep to finish.

Use [the waitFor method](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/Process.html#waitFor%28%29) :

```
Process process = new ProcessBuilder("grep", "-rni", "\"public static void main(\"", "/home/user/dev/java/").start();
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(process.getInputStream()));
process.waitFor();
String line = "";
while((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
      System.out.println(line);
}
```

Note that you may also read the output (mainly to get what happens) while it is being processed using

```
Process process = new ProcessBuilder("grep", "-rni", "\"public static void main(\"",     String line;
while (true) {
    line = reader.readLine(); // add IO exception catching
    if (line != null) {
      System.out.println(line);
    } else {
        Thread.sleep(DELAY);   // DELAY could be 100 (ms) for example     
    }
}
```

I suppose you're sure a grep launched by the owner of the java program is more than one line long ?

Comment: Thanks for your response! I have tried that as well (although it doesn't show in my example). I just tried again when I received your response, and still with no luck. I have also tried spawning a separate Thread that creates the process and runs it with the same result. I have also tried creating a Thread that just handles handling the BufferedReader object with the same result.

Comment: Did you look at the ErrorStream ?

Comment: Yes I have captured the error stream as well. I had a separate implementation where I created one thread to handle the InputStream and one to handle the ErrorStream. I'll post the updated code now.

Comment: Could you try to print during the execution using my second suggestion ?

Comment: Did you check a grep launched by the user launching the java program is more than one line long ?

Comment: yes, launching the same grep command from the terminal yields the response that I indicate "should be getting" (3 lines). I'm only getting the first line as a response with an exit value of 0, indicating no errors

Answer (score 0):

The other reason could be your process is still running but your Java program just exited.

Use the process.waitFor(); and Read your input stream in a thread.

Start the process.
Lunch a thread with the process input stream as the input.
Now wait for the process to exit by using process.waitFor();

This might help!

Comment: Thanks for responding! If you look at some of my edits above, I believe I have tried doing what you've suggested with the same result... I have created a separate Thread from which I accept the InputStream and ErrorStream of the grep process...

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this project for grep in java https://code.google.com/p/grep4j